# Trying to Copy Data from a Specified User's Network Drive but Getting an Error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to use a script to restore a backed-up folder that was created before upgrading a user's computer to windows 10.

The script asks for the subfolder that the user's home folder is located under and the user's username. Once it has both of those, it inputs the values of those variables into a network path, and then maps that network path to the H drive of the admin account used to open CMD.

However, after entering the users credentials when the script attempts to access the specified folder, I get this error:

> "System error 1312 has occurred. A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

Here is my script:

```
@echo off

:main

set /p location=Please enter the location of the user (These can be located at \\<domain>\root\HOMES): 
set /p usern=Please enter the username: 
net use H: \\<domain>\root\HOMES\%location%\%usern%\win10backup

echo Before proceeding, please confirm that the backup folder is named "win10backup"  (without quotes)
set /p input=Enter 'y' to continue: 

xcopy H:\win10backup C:\Users\%username%\ /O /X /E /H /K
```

Note:  is my companies domain. Removed for security reasons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you bothering to map the unc path to a drive letter? XCOPY works fine with UNC paths.

Comment: What are the contents in the ...\%usern%\win10backup folder? Would they happen to be user home folders? If so, I think you need to assign the backup privilege for the administrator running the script. Some domain policies have special users for backup and restore and don't allow admins access to them from their every day logon.